# Perform Action Serverside - started serverside

Tags: php, linux, webserver

I'm actually coding a web page, that offers some functions to the user on the other end.

But now I have to run scripts, even if the page is not visited, so the script has to run serverside, started by the server itself.

I think you could compare it to ebay, I guess they run scripts too, if an auction is finished and the winner gets a mail.

The script has to access a database and interact with it, and because I developed most of things in PHP it would be great if I could run the script with PHP too.

Comment: You need to investigate `cron`.

Comment: `I think you could compare it to ebay, I guess they run scripts too, if an auction is finished and the winner gets a mail.` It is called observer design pattern. All observers will get annoucement about end of auction, etc.

Comment: @MikeBrant I know about cron jobs, but I would like to run the script not every x Minutes, but on action like (competition to ebay again): 'An auction has finished -> so set the flags in the database and send a mail.'

Comment: But something is needed to check if auction has been finished.

Comment: Yes, but if I run cron jobs and one of them takes longer it could end up with x parallel running scripts that slow down or crash the server...